# Nested Form Array Woes: ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 0 -> code'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am seeking help on a

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 0 -> code'
```

error that I keep getting in the console from this code. I've consulted StackOverflow and changed some things but the error prevails.

My Typescript File is as below

```js
export class SurveyBuilderPageComponent {
  @Input()
  get survey() {
    return this._survey
  }
  set survey(value: Survey) {
    this._survey = value
    const survey: Survey = value || {
      id: null,
      title: '',
      subtitle: '',
      questions: [
        {
          code: '',
          category: '',
          title: '',
          text: '',
          type: '',
          date: '',
        },
      ],
    }

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [survey.title, Validators.required],
      subtitle: [survey.subtitle, Validators.required],
      questions: this.formBuilder.array(
        survey.questions.map((question) =>
          this.formBuilder.group({
            code: [question.code],
            category: [question.category, Validators.required],
            title: [question.title],
            text: [question.text, Validators.required],
            type: [question.type],
            date: [question.date],
          })
        )
      ),
    })
  }
  @Output() save = new EventEmitter()

  _survey: Survey

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private surveyService: SurveyService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  form: FormGroup

  private newQuestionFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      text: ['', Validators.required],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.save.emit(
        this.survey.id
          ? { ...this.form.value, id: this.survey.id }
          : this.form.value
      )
    }
  }
  handleAddNewQuestion() {
    const questions = this.form.get('questions') as FormArray
    this.insertQuestion(questions.controls.length)
  }

  private insertQuestion(index: number) {
    const questions = this.form.get('questions') as FormArray
    questions.insert(index, this.newQuestionFormGroup())
  }

  get questions(): AbstractControl[] {
    return (this.form.get('questions') as FormArray).controls
  }

  handleDeleteQuestion(index: number) {
    const questions = this.form.get('questions') as FormArray
    questions.removeAt(index)
  }

  handleInsertAfterQuestion(event: Event, index: number) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    this.insertQuestion(index + 1)
  }

  handleInsertBeforeQuestion(event: Event, index: number) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    this.insertQuestion(index)
  }
}
```

My HTML file

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="survey">
  <h2>Survey Details</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="title-field">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="title-field">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Subtitle" formControlName="subtitle" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <!--create questions section-->
    <h2>Questions</h2>
    <div class="field-space">
      <!--we should pick a spacing class standard-->

      <ng-container formGroupName="questions">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions; let idx=index">
          <mat-expansion-panel [formGroupName]="idx" [expanded]="true">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-title class="line-height-40px">
                  <mat-icon class="line-height-40px margin-right-half-em">post_add</mat-icon>
                  Question {{idx+1}}
                  <button mat-icon-button (click)="handleInsertBeforeQuestion($event, idx)">
                    <mat-icon>navigate_before</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button (click)="handleInsertAfterQuestion($event, idx)">
                    <mat-icon>navigate_next</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button (click)="handleDeleteQuestion(idx)">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </mat-panel-title>
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

            <div class="field-space">
              <mat-form-field class="title-field">
                <input matInput placeholder="Question Code" formControlName="code" />
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div class="field-space">
              <mat-form-field class="title-field">
                <input matInput formControlName="text" placeholder="Question Text" />
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="field-space">
              <mat-select placeholder="Category" class="question-dropdown" formControlName="category">
                <mat-option value="End Users">End Users</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Engagement">Engagement</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Foundations">Foundation</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Impediments">Impediments</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Product">Product</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Scaling">Scaling</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Team">Team</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Technical">Technical</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </div>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="field-space">
      <button mat-button color="secondary" (click)="handleAddNewQuestion()">
        New Question
      </button>
      <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" color="primary">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The repo is in the below link

https://github.com/jbrockSTL/misc/tree/main/survey-builder-page

Comment: Questions is an array. You should be using formArrayName, not formGroupName

Comment: I believe I did define the FormArray. Sorry, not following...

Comment: In as much as the link provides your code, Please share your code on SO, That way if the link for some reason gets broken the information is still available on SO

Comment: You has an error when you use the formArray, you use `<ng-container formGroupName="questions"> //<--ERRORR` should be `<ng-container formArrayName="questions">`. BTW it's more easy to help you if you use stackblitz, simply entry in https://stackblitz.com/ and create a new Angular (or put your code in the question)

Comment: SO blocked me from adding the code snippets in. Said it was too much code and it recommended that I link to a repo. Trust me, I tried. J Setting up StackBlitz now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve such an error is to follow the error;

`Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 0 -> code'"`

> questions - formArray 
> 0 -> formGroup 
> code -> formControl

Your html structure should reflect this
Change `<ng-container formGroupName="questions">` to `<ng-container formArrayName="questions">`

The next error you are getting while you try to add a new question is

`Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 1 -> code'"`

Note the "1"

This implies that the form array is working and the only issue is the Form Control `code`

If you look at your `newQuestionFormGroup()`, `code` is missing

```
 private newQuestionFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ["", Validators.required],
      text: ["", Validators.required],
      category: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Simply add `code` and the function will work

[See this Solution on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2j8k2e)
With the above the structure is now met and the code should work

Comment: Still getting "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 0 -> code'" even when I change to formArrayName. This error occurs when I attempt to execute the handleAddNewQuestion() function.

Comment: Yes! This fixed it! Now, I just need to handle field state and we are off to the races! Thank you!